# Godot or LibGDX for 2d game

Tags: libgdx, godot

I know that there is no correct answer for all cases, especially since LibGDX is a library and Godot is an engine, but i wanted to know what would be the best for my case.

I'm already experienced in Java, in fact, i have already made some games on it before (using another library instead of LibGDX) however, most of those games where just minor school projects so i never really cared that much about it being compatible with many platforms.

Now i'm thinking of starting a new project. And i thougth LibGDX would be a good tool, since i'm already experienced in Java and i'm more of a code person (i don't like engines that much). However i heard on many places that Java isn't a good language for games in general, specially for PC games (which is the kind of game i want to do), as Java games tend to slow down and, of course, they need Java to run (and i mean, most modern games need some kind of API or program to run, it's just that Java isn't as common to install for a game as, let's say .NET framework). So i decided to look for an alternative

Then i found godot, as i said, i'm not a big fan of engines, as i usually prefer to have almost full control over the game. however, since godot is compatible with C++ and can run on many platforms i thought maybe i should use it as a replacement (also you can use GDscript, although you don't have as much control as if you were coding the game by hand).
So my question is, in order to make a solid game, should i stick with Godot? or should i go with LibGDX?

Comment: Questions like this are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow. You could ask on a game development related forum, but brace yourself for opinionated answers. It would probably be better to take a close look at both engines/frameworks and maybe try to make a mini game in both to figure out which one you prefer.

Comment: My bad, didn't think this would be considered off-topic. Anyway, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a good question indeed. I am actually trying different engine/framework for my projects. I have made a couple of apps on the google store with godot + 1 coded in pure java.

My results so far:
- godot is **very fun** and you can do **anything you want with it** (I haven't tested 3D only 2D).

> i usually prefer to have almost full control over the game

With GDScript you have **FULL** control over your game.

The only downside for me is the size of the apk (a basic project is **30mb** once installed on the device). In your case that won't be a problem since you develop for PC (expect the same size?)

**LibGDX**, I have been trying to use it for the last couple of weeks (I have some java background so I naturally tried it). **RESULTS**: it is much much **harder** than godot! For a simple project you have to figure out a lot of things.
I really want to persevere because the size of the apk is only 2mb! but is it worth all the efforts?

Right now I am trying **gideros** which is quite **fun** to use but very few tutorials on it and the language is lua.

In short go for **GODOT**, you will love it with plenty of tutorials!

Hope this helps.
Peace.

Comment: Since the app size isn't a big deal for me i guess i'll go for godot, maybe give LibGDX a try to have an idea of how it works, thanks a lot!

Comment: hello there, I have edited my post ;-)

Comment: nope cannot edit my post. But there is another great engine GIDEROS STUDIO. Give it a try, it rocks!